# Python как значения из списка присвоить динамическим переменным

Tags: python, html, list, table, jinja2

Kак значения из списка присвоить переменным?

Чтобы переменные динамически сами создавались в зависимости от величины списка?

```
res = [1, 2, 3, 4 ...]
```

Xочу переменные передать в шаблон для генерации html страницы, данные будут записываться в таблицу. Использую библиотеку jinja2.

Или может можно передать список? Понятия не имею как значения из списка расставить по ячейкам таблицы, проще передать в переменные и в шаблоне привязать переменные к ячейкам.

Посоветуйте как быть?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не надо делать кучу переменных. Просто передай список и в jinja2 напиши вот так:

```
{% for elem in your_list %} — your_list это твой список
{{ elem }} — тут делай, что хочешь
{% endfor %}
```

Если используешь flask(кстати очень рекомендую — круто!), то сделай вот так:

```
# views.py

@route('your/route')
def go():
    render_template('your_template.html', your_list=your_list) #your_list should be init'ed
```

---

Ну а теоретически можно создать кучу переменных из списка, только ***очень не рекомендую***:

```
for i, j in enumerate(your_list):
    exec('var' + str(i) + '=' + '"' + j + '"')
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот так вот:

```
res = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for v in res:
    exec(f'variable_{v} = {v}')

print(variable_1)
```

Comment: Блин, я это уже написал, чуть быстрее тебя (

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica у меня показывает, что "ответ дан 2 минуты назад", "изменён 1 минуту назад"

Comment: Ладно, только этот ответ, даже не предупреждает, что так делать нельзя. Тем более, я сохранил правку и тут "новый ответ на вопрос".

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica я ни в чём вас не обвинял :) Раньше или позже — неважно. Важно, чтобы ответ отвечал на вопрос

Comment: Кстати твой код не будет работать с `res = ['@', '$', '!']`. см. мой